# Simplifying Terms in a Matrix

Tags: matrix, algebraic-manipulation

Given the following 3 matrices:

```
M1=1/3*{{1,1,1},{1,α,α^2},{1,α^2,α]}} 
Z1={{Z+Zg,Zg,Zg},{Zg,Z+Zg,Zg},{Zg,Zg,Z+Zg}} 
M2={{1,1,1},{1,α^2,α},{1,α,α^2}}
```

where alpha is 1@120 degrees or -.5+ I Sqrt[3]/2 in rectangular form.

I would like to find what M1.Z1.M2 is. However, whenever I do:

```
M1.Z1.M2 /. α-> -.5+ I Sqrt[3]/2
```

I get a rather unwieldy answer.

I expect the terms that are X+X*alpha+X*alpha^2 should equal 0 (because the vector addition of 1@0+1@120+1@240=0). Why is this not working as expected? What do I need to change to get the result:

```
{{Z+3Zg,0,0},{0,Z,0},{0,0,Z}}//MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution to this is to a combination of Simplify and Chop, which will get rid of items like (0. * I).

```
Chop[Simplify[M1.Z1.M2 /. α -> (-0.5 + I*Sqrt[3]/2)]]
```

> {{Z + 3 Zg, 0, 0}, {0, 1. Z, 0}, {0, 0, 1. Z}}

There are still some (1. Z) terms in there, which, if you look at the FullForm are actually just very close to 1, according to the numerical calculation:

```
FullForm[%]
```

> List[List[Plus[Z, Times[3, Zg]], 0, 0], List[0, Times[0.9999999999999998`, Z], 0], List[0, 0, Times[0.9999999999999998`, Z]]]

This could be fixed in a few ways; the simplest is to just replace the close values like this:

```
Chop[Simplify[M1.Z1.M2 /. α -> (-0.5 + I*Sqrt[3]/2)]] /. r_Real /; Chop[r - 1] == 0 :> 1
```

> {{Z + 3 Zg, 0, 0}, {0, Z, 0}, {0, 0, Z}}

However, all of these are a bit unwieldly, and an even better solution is to remove the numerical component to the calculation altogether by replacing -0.5 with -1/2:

```
Simplify[M1.Z1.M2 /. α -> (-1/2 + I*Sqrt[3]/2)]
```

> {{Z + 3 Zg, 0, 0}, {0, Z, 0}, {0, 0, Z}}

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the numerical component part in your answer - It was insightful.

Answer (score 1):

```
M1.Z1.M2 /. α -> -.5 + I Sqrt[3]/2

Chop[FullSimplify[%]]
```

(*
{{Z + 3 Zg, 0, 0}, {0, 1. Z, 0}, {0, 0, 1. Z}}
*)

Answer (score 1):

```
M1 = 1/3*{{1, 1, 1}, {1, α, α^2}, {1, α^2, α}};
Z1 = {{Z + Zg, Zg, Zg}, {Zg, Z + Zg, Zg}, {Zg, Zg, Z + Zg}};
M2 = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, α^2, α}, {1, α, α^2}};
```

Either provide an exact value in the `Rule`

```
M1.Z1.M2 /. α -> -1/2 + I Sqrt[3]/2 // Simplify
```

> {{Z + 3 Zg, 0, 0}, {0, Z, 0}, {0, 0, Z}}

Or use `Rationalize` to remove both near zero values and `1.` factors

```
M1.Z1.M2 /. α -> -.5 + I Sqrt[3]/2 // Simplify // 
 Rationalize[#, 10^-10] &
```

> {{Z + 3 Zg, 0, 0}, {0, Z, 0}, {0, 0, Z}}